# angular.js loaded instead of angular.min.js with requirejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, webjars

I'm using Webjars to import AngularJS into my web project. 
For some reason the minified version of AngularJS won't be served even though I'm referencing those in my main. I was expecting to see angular.min.js and angular-route.min.js being loaded, but I'm seeing the regular angular.js and angular-route.js. What am I doing wrong here?

My main.js:

```
'use strict';

requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    'angular': '../lib/angularjs/angular.min',
    'angular-route': '../lib/angularjs/angular-route.min',
    'async': '../lib/requirejs-plugins/src/async'
  },
  shim: {
    'angular': {
      exports : 'angular'
    },
    'angular-route': {
      deps: ['angular'],
      exports : 'angular'
    }
  }
});

require(['angular', './controllers', './directives', './filters', './services', 'angular-route','./places-autocomplete','async','./gmaps'],
    function(angular, controllers) {
        initialize();

        // Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
        angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.filters', 'myApp.services', 'myApp.directives', 'ngRoute']).
        config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
            ....
        }]);

        angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);

    });
```

My html loads requirejs like this:

```
<script>
   @Html(org.webjars.RequireJS.getSetupJavaScript(routes.WebJarAssets.at("").url))
</script>
<script data-main="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/main.js")"
        src="@routes.WebJarAssets.at(WebJarAssets.locate("require.min.js"))"></script>
```

and the above requirejs.config snippet resides in main.js

Comment: It is only an assumption. You did not add the extension '.js' after the file paths. Perhaps requirejs adds it automatically. But, it might be confused by the .min extension that is unknown to requirejs. And because there is allready an extension (.min) it refuses adding the .js extension. Or it replaces the unknown  .min by .js. Please, try to add the .js to you path.

Comment: Kinda surprised, but this actually works. As you said, requirejs is supposed to add it automatically.

Comment: That's what I expected. At the moment I'm to busy but this evening (MESZ) I will have a look at the source code of requirejs. But I'm pretty sure that they check if there is already an extension with a regular expression e.g. `/\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*/`, If there is one they do not add a .js to the path.  They do not check for .js  because it also possible to have another extension .ts = typeScript or .coffee for coffeeScript or when one uses the text file extension for example: https://github.com/requirejs/text.

Comment: Likely your config is being set too late.  Are you using the built-in WebJar RequireJS configs?

Comment: That might be, see my updated answer. How should I load instead? But also note that @PeterPaulKiefer's solution to add .js at the end in my current config also works.

Comment: @Daniel What kicks off the loading of your application? There should be a `require` call somewhere but there is no `require` call in what you show in your question. By the way, it is not the case that when presented with `angular.min`, RequireJS will treat `.min` as an extension and not add the `.js` at then end. How do I know? I've got dozens of path names with `.min` (or other stuff) and it works find. RequireJS will add the `.js` for you.

Comment: @Louis See my updated answer. I basically started from the example  angular-seed-play on Typesafehub and went from there.

Comment: Now I found a reason. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into the sources of requirejs. Here's what I found:

requirejs splits each path, you defined in the config object, into its components (i.e. the directories, the filename and the extension). For some reason (node module naming conventions) the last extension is dropped. They do not check if that's a '.js'. Then this path array is used to access a module. Without a plugin rquirejs only handles .js files. It adds a .js if nessecary.

Now you can see what happens in your example. In the first step requirejs drops the .min extension. When it loads the module it joins the path components and adds a .js to the end. Then it loads the full module and not the minified version.

If you add a .js to your paths, then this .js was dropped and the .min is still there.

Comment: Oh, so basically it would work if you put .dummy at the end as well? Good research, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add 
`enforceDefine: true,`

Comment: I now get an error saying "Error: No define call for 8ed77fe0a67749dbf6a3ae97ffc69e7b-main". So what does this mean? I'm pretty new to requirejs, not sure how to move on.

Comment: There can be 3 reasons. Read more here http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#nodefine